# How to capture the count of processed records from Sqoop import?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, sqoop, sqoop2

To replicate the data from my DB to S3 I am using below command.

```
sqoop import -D mapreduce.job.name= xxx-D mapred.job.queue.name=user -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=<path> -Dfs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm=<xx>--options-file <path> --query "select col1,ID,UPDATETIME from db.table where UPDATETIME between to_date('2015-09-11 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2018-05-24 04:28:16','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') and \$CONDITIONS" --hive-delims-replacement ' ' --direct --m 1 --split-by ID  --target-dir <s3//path>
```

I am able to replicate the data but I need to get the count of processed data from the same command without using other commands like eval. Because meanwhile other records may got ingested into the source.

What I want is to capture this record count:

```
18/05/21 22:55:55 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 47.9229 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
18/05/21 22:55:55 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 33372 records.
```

Comment: for quick help add the tag of amazon-s3 also.

Comment: Would be parsing the logs in parallel like `&& grep -o "Retrieved.*records" /<yourSqoopJobLog>` feasible for you?

Comment: how exactly it can be done? can you explain please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found way for the above query. when you pass your sqoop command in below 
`subprocess` program and use .communicate to store the whole output along with warning and info messages.

```
sqoop_command ='sqoop import........'

process = subprocess.Popen(sqoop_command , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

rec_str = process.communicate()
```

rec_str contains the output.